# AD and BC or CE and BCE?

Tags: discussion, spelling

Which year convention should a Buddhist website use?

Or should we use the Buddhist calendar? As far as I can tell, the Buddhist calendar, is actually the Thai Calendar, which is just a Gregorian calendar with a 500 or so year shift.

Comment: Probably, Buddhist website should use that year convention that everybody can understand.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No one but a devout Christian should be using AD and BC anymore. The Gregorian calendar is standard in Thailand and Sri Lanka, but the Buddhist calendar follows the moons. So, in Thailand, today is waning day seven of the eight month of the year.

As for year, the (Theravada) Buddhist calendar starts after the Buddha's parinibbana, so depending on which calculation you go by, we're at approximately year 2557 B.E. (Buddhist Era).

Because the calculation varies from country to country, my inclination is to use C.E. and B.C.E., in spite of their obvious ties to Christianity.